# Where can I find the CSS properties order used by Stylelint?

Tags: css, npm, sass, stylelint

Using [Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/), I have the CSS order option activated. 
I haven't been able to set up [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) to show the errors. 
Where can I find the used declaration/property order?

Here is my [`.stylelintrc.js`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure) :

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: ['stylelint-config-standard', 'stylelint-config-concentric-order'],
  rules: {
    'at-rule-no-unknown': [
      true,
      { ignoreAtRules: ['mixin', 'if', 'else', 'include', 'extend'] },
    ],
    'max-nesting-depth': 4,
    indentation: 4,
    'selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown': [
      true,
      { ignorePseudoElements: ['v-deep'] },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [extending](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure/#extends) the [stylelint-config-concentric-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-concentric-order) community config. This config includes and configures the [stylelint-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-order) community [plugin](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure/#plugins). You can [find the order of the properties](https://github.com/chaucerbao/stylelint-config-concentric-order/blob/master/src/index.js) in the [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/chaucerbao/stylelint-config-concentric-order).

You can see Stylelint errors in VS Code using [the official Stylelint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint).

And you can have the extension automatically fix problems on save, which will include the order of your properties, using the [`editor.codeActionsOnSave`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint#editor.codeactionsonsave) configuration property:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  },
  "stylelint.validate": ["css", "postcss","scss"],
  "css.validate": false,
  "scss.validate": false
}
```

Alternatively, you can run `npx stylelint "**/*.scss" --fix"` on the command line to automatically fix problems.